# Answer after "Morid haTal" in the Amida

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, chazzan-prayer-leader, geshem-tal-ruach

In my shul, people answer something after "Morid hatal" in the Hazara of the Amida. It sounds like "Livraha". Do you know what word it is exactly and what it means?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

According to [this article](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/toshba/minhagim/tu-tfi.htm) from the Da'at website:

During the repetition of the *amida*, it is the Tunisian custom for the congregation to respond "*livracha*" (meaning "for blessing") after the words "*Morid hageshem*" (meaning "He brings down the rain", recited during the winter months) or "*Morid hatal*" (meaning "He brings down the dew", recited during the summer months).